# Java - Program Synchronization With Server

Tags: java, synchronization, client-server

While learning Java I have come across a lot of questions regarding how to program something 'the best way'. An example is a chat program.

When a changes their status, display name, display picture or personal message it sends a request to the server and the server keeps all the server data in memory. My question is: Is it good practice to avoid database I/O and keep everything sync'd in memory. So if a user changes their display name should I update the users status in memory on the server AND update it in the database? Or wait till the user disconnects and then write their information to database?

I hope I am clear. This goes for all different kinds of programs, syncing settings ect..

I ask this because if the server crashes then all the data in memory wouldnt be saved in the database and user info would be rolled back.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Which event do you suppose will happen more frequently - users changing their name, or users disconnecting?

Comment: Disconnecting from my experiences?

Comment: So, if you do the database updates when the information is changed, you'll have both fewer database queries and better data persistence?  The choice seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, there is no single "best practice".  at best, there are probably a handful of "best practices" covering a variety of more specific use cases.  as already pointed out in the comments on the OP, there are various questions that come up, e.g.:

- frequency of data modification
- app speed requirements
- available memory
- data size
- acceptability of stale data
- acceptability of lost data

until you start answering these questions, no one can start giving concrete recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, I will take these factors into consideration.